# Create JSON from string, to use as object

Tags: jquery, json

So I want to create this JSON object:

```
{
   "id":"3",
   "created":"0000-00-00",
   "parentIDs":null,
   "childIDs":"",
   "uid":"movies",
   "title":"Movies",
   "related":"movies",
   "pos":"",
   "css":"{ "background-image":"-webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(46,44,46) 49%, rgb(18,17,18) 75%)" }"
}
```

from string:

```
value = ""id":"3","created":"0000-00-00","parentIDs":null,"childIDs":"","uid":"imdb","title":"Imdb","related":"movies","pos":"""
```

This string comes from a database, so I can't really change the formatting, but it should be correct like this.

(This string originates from an array of similiar strings, which I iterate through, somehow losing the {} around them)

I tried removing the outer quotes with `value.substr(1, value.length - 2);`. And then convert it with `.toJSON();` but it only adds a whole lot of extra slashes I don't need.

I just need to add `{}` around it, and then javascript would see it as a JSON object.

Is there any shorthand way of doing that? or is there a small library that can convert my messy string in a clever way to a JSON object?

```
[update]
```

I tried: `eval('{' + value + '}');` But i get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` in Chrome.

I tried JSON.parse but get: `TypeError: JSON.parse is not a function` in Chrome and Firefox, it must be the string's formatting. I'm beginning to suspect the "css" entry, although it starts complaining at the first "id" entry, it's expecting a function instead of JSON?

(I cut down the raw JSON, but forgot the most important "css" one)

[update2]

Ok, so I changed the css data to `'` instead of `"`, now it will actually parse, but now my script is broken, because I'm expecting raw CSS from the db, any way to change the resulting `'css':'blabla'` to: `"css":"blabla"` ?

Comment: There is no such thing as a JSON object. There are JSON strings and JavaScript objects; which of the two do you want to get? Also, are you sure there is no better way? "I iterate through" tells me that it's your code that produces this, so other options should be available.

Comment: *"I just need to add {} around it, and then javascript would see it as a JSON object."* No. If you add `{` and `}` at the beginning and end, then you might have a string containing valid JSON (not an object). But that's what you want, right? If you want to a JavaScript object instead, you would have to pass the new string to `JSON.parse`. I think you should have a look at http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/, to get a better idea of the differences between JSON and JavaScript objects.

Comment: Basically I want to have a usable object, that I can access via value.id for example, which I can't do when it's a string..

Comment: @FelixKling I understand the difference, It just won't convert correctly to a usable object, for example, I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : " when I try to eval it, I don't see anything wrong with the formatting of the JSON string.

Comment: Editing this question to the extent that you have, and putting a bounty on it, is misguided. The answer to your original question - how to parse a JSON-encoded string into an object - is very simple, and is to use `JSON.parse`. If you're getting `TypeError: JSON.parse is not a function` - which I've never seen before and doesn't make much sense to me - then you need to start a new question for that and ideally ***give us a test case that lets us replicate the problem***.

Comment: @TrySpace: You cannot directly `eval` a string containing because it is not valid JavaScript. You would have to add `(...)` around the string, like `eval('(' + jsonStr + ')')`. But as already said many times, `JSON.parse` is what you should use, once you have valid JSON.

Comment: If you're getting this "TypeError" - that probably means that you have a 3rd party library that overrides the global JSON object. Have a look at the DOM tab in firebug.

Comment: @TrySpace could you please do me favor and run the fiddle from my answer and tell me if you getting the same error as you describing  ?

Answer (score 15):

If you have a string that contains valid JSON, you can convert it to a JavaScript Object using `JSON.parse()`.

Assuming you have a string:

```
value = '"id":"3","created":"0000-00-00","parentIDs":null,"childIDs":"","uid":"imdb","title":"Imdb","related":"movies","pos":""';
```

you would then do:

```
obj = JSON.parse("{"+value+"}");JSON
```

Note it needs the `{}` as part of the string to be a valid JSON string.

Comment: Tried this, but get "TypeError: JSON.parse is not a function" everytime.. Probably because it is not correct JSON

Comment: What browser are you using? JSON.parse is available in pretty much every current browser - http://caniuse.com/json

Comment: @TrySpace: No that has nothing to do with it. Your browser just doesn't seem to implement that feature. You can include json3 in that case: https://github.com/bestiejs/json3.

Comment: @FelixKling that's weird because in other contexts it does work, the function definately exists, but it looks like it throws an error because it cannot 'compute'

Comment: @TrySpace: If you use jQuery (you added this tag to your question), can you try `$.parseJSON("{"+value+"}")` instead of the native `JSON.parse("{"+value+"}")` function ?

Answer (score 6):

ok, so this is the best I could come up with:

```
var value = '"id":"3","created":"0000-00-00","parentIDs":null,"childIDs":"","uid":"imdb","title":"Imdb","related":"movies","pos":"","css":"{ "background-image":"-webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(46,44,46) 49%, rgb(18,17,18) 75%)" }"';
var nestedObjects = [];
String.prototype.trimQuotes = function () {
    return this.indexOf('"') === this.lastIndexOf('"') ? this.substring(this.indexOf('"') + 1) : this.substring(this.indexOf('"') + 1, this.lastIndexOf('"'));
};
function convertObject(str) {
    var retObj = {};
    $.each(str.split(','), function () {
        var keypair = this.split(':');
        if (keypair.length < 2) { return; }
        retObj[keypair[0].trimQuotes().trim()] = keypair[1].indexOf('@') > -1 ? nestedObjects[parseInt(keypair[1].trimQuotes().substring(1), 10)].trimQuotes().trim() : keypair[1].trimQuotes();
    });
    return retObj;
}
var temp = value.split('{')[0];
$.each(value.split('{'), function (i, t) {
    if (i === 0) {
        return;
    }
    var splits = t.split('}');
    nestedObjects.push(splits[0]);
    temp += '@' + (i - 1);
    if (splits.length > 1) {
        temp += splits[1];
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SkCVd/5/

Answer (score 4):

It's inbuild option in `jquery` to parse string into Json.

as

```
  var str = '{   "id":"3",   "created":"0000-00-00",   "parentIDs":null,   "childIDs":"",   "uid":"movies",   "title":"Movies",   "related":"movies",   "pos":"",   "css":"{ background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(46,44,46) 49%, rgb(18,17,18) 75%) }"}';
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var result = jQuery.parseJSON(str);
        console.log(result);
    });
```

removed `"` from CSS portion 
Here is output 
[image]
refer below url http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Answer (score 3):

here is a parser using regx!

```
var tmp = '"id":"3","created":"0000-00-00","parentIDs":null,"childIDs":"","uid":"imdb","title":"Imdb","related":"movies","pos":"","css":"{ "background-image":"-webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(46,44,46) 49%, rgb(18,17,18) 75%)" }"' ;
var reg = /"(\w+)":(?:"([\w-]*)"|"{([^}]*)}"|(null))/g;
var obj ={};
tmp.replace(reg,function(text,all,dall,hall,vall){
    obj[all]=hall||dall||vall;
    console.log(all +":"+obj[all]);
});
```

its quite simple isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a bit of a workaround if you say the reason your string isn't parsing is because the next dimension of your JSON array is wrapped in quotes. I'm sure there is a better way though.

```
var value = '"id":"3","created":"0000-00-00","parentIDs":null,"childIDs":"","uid":"imdb","title":"Imdb","related":"movies","pos":"","css":"{ "background-image":"-webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(46,44,46) 49%, rgb(18,17,18) 75%)" }"';

value = value.replace("\"{", "{");
value = value.replace("}\"", "}");

value = "{"+value+"}";
value = JSON.parse(value);

console.log(value);
```

And here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bambattajb/9LLLk/1/)

Answer (score 2):

As everyone already mentioned `jQuery.parseJSON()` is the way. In your case you need to clean up the string you getting from SQL first, otherwise you won't be able to parse into correct json:

```
// format from SQL : value = "validJSON"
var fromSQL  = 'value = ""id":"3","created":"0000-00-00","parentIDs":null,"childIDs":"","uid":"imdb","title":"Imdb","related":"movies","pos":"""';

// we need to remove  @value ="' at the beginnig and '"' at the end  
var withoutWrapper = fromSQL.substring(('value = "').length, fromSQL.length-1);

// now add {} to make it as a json obj
var withNewWrapper = '{' +withoutWrapper +'}';

// parse it
var json= jQuery.parseJSON(withNewWrapper);
```

Here is functional example : http://jsfiddle.net/vojtiik/pzJTa/

Tools such as this [JsonViewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) always helps !

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
var str = '{"id":"3",
"created":"0000-00-00",
"parentIDs":null,
"childIDs":"",
"uid":"movies",
"title":"Movies",
"related":"movies",
"pos":""}',
    foo = JSON.parse(str);
```

It could certainly look cleaner though.

Comment: The string is not valid JSON though.

Comment: @FelixKling What about now?

Comment: Better, but it's not what the OP has. You probably have to explain how to convert the OP's string into a string containing valid JSON.

Comment: Tried this, but get "TypeError: JSON.parse is not a function" everytime.. Probably because it is not correct JSON

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
  var arr = new Function('return {' + value + '}')();
```

This is safer and faster equivalent for `eval` and JSON.parse for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are not receiving this string with AJAX, but embedding it directly in some script on server side - so there is no need to parse it at client(JSON.parse is not needed here). All you need is to correctly write object data according JSON rules:

```
var data_object = {
 "id":"3",
   "created":"0000-00-00",
   "parentIDs":null,
   "childIDs":"",
   "uid":"movies",
   "title":"Movies",
   "related":"movies",
   "pos":"",
   "css":'{ "background-image":"-webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(46,44,46) 49%, rgb(18,17,18) 75%)" }'

}
```

Pay attention to css property (if you want to include quotes in string you can simply use different quotes for marking begin and end of the string). There is not other way - you just have to properly quote your string constants.